# one to one mapping annotation hibernate

Tags: hibernate-mapping

Hi i am trying to make a simple programm in java of one two one mapping hibernate.But When I ran the programme i Have some error as per below.and i want to make a entry of table through annotaion in MySql.But it will throw some sql grammer exception.please help e to solve my problem.

```
Here is My files..

Pojo CLass Stack

package com.hibernate;



import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;


@Entity
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "javadb", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
public class Stock implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer stockId;
    private String stockCode;
    private String stockName;
    private StockDetail stockDetail;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    public Stock(String stockCode, String stockName, StockDetail stockDetail) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
        this.stockName = stockName;
        this.stockDetail = stockDetail;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getStockId() {
        return this.stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    @Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getStockCode() {
        return this.stockCode;
    }

    public void setStockCode(String stockCode) {
        this.stockCode = stockCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "STOCK_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
    public String getStockName() {
        return this.stockName;
    }

    public void setStockName(String stockName) {
        this.stockName = stockName;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stock", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public StockDetail getStockDetail() {
        return this.stockDetail;
    }

    public void setStockDetail(StockDetail stockDetail) {
        this.stockDetail = stockDetail;
    }

}


Here My Another Pojo class Stock Detail

package com.hibernate;



import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock_detail", catalog = "javadb")
public class StockDetail implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer stockId;
    private Stock stock;
    private String compName;
    private String compDesc;
    private String remark;
    private Date listedDate;

    public StockDetail() {
    }

    public StockDetail(Stock stock, String compName, String compDesc,
            String remark, Date listedDate) {
        this.stock = stock;
        this.compName = compName;
        this.compDesc = compDesc;
        this.remark = remark;
        this.listedDate = listedDate;
    }

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "stock"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "STOCK_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getStockId() {
        return this.stockId;
    }

    public void setStockId(Integer stockId) {
        this.stockId = stockId;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Stock getStock() {
        return this.stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Stock stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Column(name = "COMP_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getCompName() {
        return this.compName;
    }

    public void setCompName(String compName) {
        this.compName = compName;
    }

    @Column(name = "COMP_DESC", nullable = false)
    public String getCompDesc() {
        return this.compDesc;
    }

    public void setCompDesc(String compDesc) {
        this.compDesc = compDesc;
    }

    @Column(name = "REMARK", nullable = false)
    public String getRemark() {
        return this.remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "LISTED_DATE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getListedDate() {
        return this.listedDate;
    }

    public void setListedDate(Date listedDate) {
        this.listedDate = listedDate;
    }

}

Here is my Data Insert class

package com.hibernate;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hibernate one to one (Annotation)");
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Stock stock = new Stock();

        stock.setStockCode("7052");
        stock.setStockName("PADINI");

        StockDetail stockDetail=new StockDetail();

        stockDetail.setCompName("PADINI Holding Malaysia");
        stockDetail.setCompDesc("one stop shopping");
        stockDetail.setRemark("vinci vinci");
        stockDetail.setListedDate(new Date());

        stock.setStockDetail(stockDetail);
        stockDetail.setStock(stock);

        session.save(stock);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}


here is my HibernateUtil class for connection file

package com.hibernate;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
and here is my configuration class

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
         <property name="show_sql">true</property>
         <mapping class="com.hibernate.Stock"/>
         <mapping class="com.hibernate.StockDetail"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

And My error is shown as below

Hibernate one to one (Annotation)
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: insert into javadb.stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.hibernate.Stock]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2108)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2588)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at com.hibernate.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'javadb.stock' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1153)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1318)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1303)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:33)
    ... 16 more
    enter code here
```

Please help e to solve my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the exception stack trace clearly. Table does not exist.

Either you create the table or set the hbm2ddl property in hibernate config

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'javadb.stock' doesn't exist
```

Comment: I have added this property   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property> but getiing error like log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: stock

Comment: It is not reflected in the configuration file you have put in the question.

Comment: The error speaks for itself. You have to either create the table on your own in the database using CREATE TABLE DDL or set the hbm2ddl.auto property to create-drop or create